# Property 'object's properties' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this kind of code:

spear.ts:

```
export class Spears {
    constructor(
        id: string = null,
        transaction_id: string = null,
        spear_id: number = null,
        delivery_date: any = null,
        delivery_time: any = null,
        ...
    ) {}
}
```

Later on, I use that class in my component.ts class and it will be assigned with data fetched from the back-end

spear.component.ts:

```
export class CpCoorPenerimaanSpearDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  spear = new Spears();
  spearForm = new Spears();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._spears.getSpearDetail().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.spear = res.data;
        this.spearForm = res.data;
      }
      err => console.log(err);
    );
  }
}
```

Everytime I want to use the value of the object it always showing error message that the property of the object does not exist of type Object. For example when I want to console.log the property just after executing `spearForm = res.data` it just show message like this:

```
Property 'spear_id' does not exist on type 'Spears'.
```

I have been struggling for 5 hours for this problem. I have looked for similar question and It said just change the type of the property to any. Event just console logging the spear_id which is in type of number, it said property does not exist.

The thing that make me confused the most is sometimes the message is not shown, but after I feel everything going well, the message shown again. Is there any help?

Comment: Try adding `public` in front of the constructor parameters for your class. Like this `public id: string = null`. For all of them. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define class properties in the correct place

```
 export class Spears {
   id: string;
   transaction_id: string;
   spear_id: number;
   delivery_date: any;
   delivery_time: any;
   constructor(data) {
      this.id = data['id'] || null;
      this.transaction_id = data['transaction_id'] || null;
      // map every field  
   }
 }
```

Then

```
this._spears.getSpearDetail().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.spear = res.data;
    this.spearForm = new Spears(res.data);
  }
  err => console.log(err);
);
```

Hope this will help!